# How does ActiveRecord handle Relationship CamelCasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a question about rails and how its relationships query builder, specifically how camel case is converted for the related calls.

Relevant Code

```
class CustomerPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :plan_id, :startDate, :user_id

  has_many :planActions
end

class PlanAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :actionType_id, :customerPlan_id, :notes, :timeSpent

  belongs_to :customerPlan
  belongs_to :actionType
end
```

The getters and setters work just fine, such as `plan_action.actionType.name` will correctly pull from the related model. However `customer_plan.planActions.each` returns the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: plan_actions.customer_plan_id: 
  SELECT "plan_actions".* 
    FROM "plan_actions"  
    WHERE "plan_actions"."customer_plan_id" = 1
```

The column is defined in the database as `customerPlan_id`, was I just wrong to use this? It works for every other call, all my other relationships work fine. Even PlanAction -> CustomerPlan.

I ran through all [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), and searched about every other source I know of. It would be simple enough to change my columns, I just want to know what's going on here.

Thank you for your time!

---

A quick fix for this is to just explicitly set the foreign_key.

```
has_many :planActions, :foreign_key => "customerPlan_id", :class_name => "PlanAction"
```

Still, I think I am missing some model naming convention somewhere, just can't seem to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails convention for DB column names is to use lowercase letters with words separated by an underscore (e.g. `author_id`, `comments_count`, `updated_at`, etc).

I would highly recommend that you stick to the Rails conventions. This would make your life much easier. To change it to the rails convention, simply create a migration to rename the column to the appropriate style.

However, if you do want to use a custom style for the column name, rails provides the `:foreign_key` option in the [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) relationship to specify the expected foreign column name:

```
class CustomerPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plan_actions, :foreign_key => 'customerPlan_id'
end
```

You can also use the `alias_attribute` macro to alias the column name, if you'd like to use a different model attribute name than the actual DB column name. But as I mentioned, I would recommend sticking to the rails convention as much as possible. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Exactly the explanation I was looking for. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Rails has 3 basic naming schemes.

One is for constants, and it is `ALL_UPPERCASE_SEPARATED_BY_UNDERSCORES`.

One is for Classes and it is `AllCamelCaseWithNoUnderscores`.

One is for variables and method names, and is `all_lowercase_separated_by_underscores`.

The reason that it is this way is not just for consistency, but also because it freely converts between them using [these methods](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveSupport/Inflector/camelize).

So, to make your posted code more rails-y:

```
class CustomerPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :plan_id, :start_date, :user_id

  has_many :plan_actions
end

class PlanAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :action_type_id, :customer_plan_id, :notes, :time_spent

  belongs_to :customer_plan
  belongs_to :action_type
end
```

Comment: You're welcome. I would really try to avoid the casing in the accepted answer, if I were you.